# Getting started with Grails Resources Plugin

Tags: java, grails, groovy, sitemesh

I am new to using Grails plugins and this is most likely a novice mistake, but I cannot find documentation that helps me, so here we go.

I have added the following file to grails-app/conf : appResources.groovy

```
//appResources.groovy
modules = {
     css{
         resource url:"/css/main.css"
     }
}
```

and in my layout file main.gsp I use `<r:layoutResources />` in the head and right before `</body>`. So far so good no errors.

Now in my view gsp I have this (in part):

```
//myView.gsp
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <r:require      module="css"       />
</head>
```

When go to view the page I now get the following error:

```
Exception Message: No module found with name [css]
Caused by: Error executing tag <g:applyLayout>: Error executing tag <r:layoutResources>: ...
```

I've done my reading, and I think I need to do something in Config.groovy to get grails to read appResources.groovy but I have no idea what to write. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard filename is `ApplicationResources.groovy`.  It will be picked up automatically.

Be sure to set [`grails.resources.work.dir`](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html) in Config.groovy to a stable location in order to prevent missing resource issues in production deployment.